# Skip first step of django two-factor auth

Tags: django, two-factor-authentication

The first step of Django two-factor auth is just a page where user is asked to click on "activate two factor authentication".

How can I skip that step `wizard.steps.current == 'welcome'` and get the user directly to the actual page where he chooses his authentication method. `wizard.steps.current == 'method'`.

```
{% if wizard.steps.current == 'welcome' %}
    ...
{% elif wizard.steps.current == 'method' %}
    ...
{% elif ... %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

A possible solution is to override the `wizard.step.current` by setting it up to `'method'` before user hit the setup.html page but I don't know to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The solution was quite easy.

1. In the core.py of the two-factor package find the class SetupView() and comment or remove the line `('welcome', Form)`
2. in the view that preceed the two factor setup insert the following code:

   `return redirect('/account/two_factor/setup/')`.

This will redirect directly the user to setup page and skip two-factor  explanatory page